# Numerical Method Simulation for 2D Advection Diffusion Equation on Python

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Here it is an Advection-Diffusion equation in 2D:
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}+U \frac{\partial C}{\partial x}+V \frac{\partial C}{\partial y}=D\left(\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2C} {\partial y^2}\right)\
$$
I transformed it into a form suitable for the solution by the FTCS numerical method, and I got the following finite difference formula
$$
C_{(j,k)}^{n+1}=\big(C_{(j+1,k)}^{n} A_1+C_{(j-1,k)}^{n} A_2+C_{(j,k+1)}^{n} A_3+C_{(j,k-1)}^{n} A_4+C_{(j,k)}^{n} A_5 \big)Δt
$$
where

- $A_1=\frac{D}{(Δx)^2}-\frac{U}{2Δx}$
- $A_2=\frac{D}{(Δx)^2}+\frac{U}{2Δx}$,
- $A_3=\frac{D}{(Δy)^2}-\frac{V}{2Δy}$
- $A_4=\frac{D}{(Δy)^2}+\frac{V}{2Δy}$
- $A_5=\frac{1}{Δt}-\frac{2D}{(Δx)^2}-\frac{2D}{(Δy)^2}$

and the boundary conditions are
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
C_{(0,k)}^{n+1} =\big(C_{(1,k)}^{n} A_1+C_{(0,k)}^{n} (A_2+A_5)-c_1ΔxA_2+C_{(0,k+1)}^{n} A_3+C_{(0,k-1)}^{n} A_4\big)Δt & j=0\\
C_{(L,k)}^{(n+1)}=\big(C_{(L,k)}^{n} (A_1+A_5)+c_2ΔxA_1+C_{(L-1,k)}^{n} A_2+C_{(L,k+1)}^{n} A_3+C_{(L,k-1)}^{n} A_4\big)Δt & j = L\\
C_{(j,0)}^{n+1}=\big(C_{(j+1,0)}^{n} A_1+C_{(j-1,0)}^{n} A_2+C_{(j,1)}^{n} A_3+C_{(j,0)}^{n} (A_4+A_5)-c_3ΔyA_4 \big)Δt & k = 0\\
C_{(j,W)}^{(n+1)} = \big(C_{(j+1,W)}^{n} A_1+C_{(j-1,W)}^{n} A_2+C_{(j,W)}^{n} (A_3+A_5)+c_4 ΔyA_3+C_{(j,W-1)}^{n} A_4 \big)Δt & k = W
\end{array}
\right.
$$ ($L$ and $W$ are integers)

Now I want coded it, but the result is not what I expected, and here is my code for a review

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

delta_X = 0.5
delta_Y = 0.5
delta_T = 0.5
L = 3
W = 3
t_akhir = 3
nL = int(((L-0)//delta_X)+1)
nW = int(((W-0)//delta_Y)+1)
nt_akhir = int(((t_akhir-0)//delta_T)+1)
D = 1
U = 1
V = 1

t = np.linspace(0, t_akhir, nt_akhir+1)
x = np.linspace(0, L, nL+1)
y = np.linspace(0, W, nW+1)

A_1 = (D/(delta_X*delta_X))-(U/(2*delta_X))
A_2 = (D/(delta_X*delta_X))+(U/(2*delta_X))
A_3 = (D/(delta_Y*delta_Y))-(V/(2*delta_Y))
A_4 = (D/(delta_Y*delta_Y))+(V/(2*delta_Y))
A_5 = (1/delta_T)-((2\*D)/(delta_X*delta_X))-((2*D)/(delta_Y*delta_Y))

C = np.empty((nL+1,nW+1,nt_akhir+1))

c_1 = 1
c_2 = 1
c_3 = 1
c_4 = 1
C[0,:,:] = c_1
C[len(x)-1,:,:] = c_2
C[:,0,:] = c_3
C[:,len(y)-1,:] = c_4

idx_t = 0
for n in t:
    idx_y = 0
    if idx_t+1 == len(t):
        break
    for k in y:# axis y 
        if idx_y+1 == len(y):
            break
        idx_x = 0
        for j in x: # axis x
            if idx_x+1 == len(x):
                break
            C[:,:,0] = idx_x*(1-idx_x)*idx_y*(1-idx_y) # initial condition
            if idx_x == 0:   
                C[idx_x,idx_y,idx_t+1] = (A_1*C[idx_x+1, idx_y, idx_t] + (A_2+A_5)*C[idx_x, idx_y, idx_t] - (c_1\*delta_X)\*A_2 + A_3*C[idx_x, idx_y+1, idx_t] + A_4*C[idx_x, idx_y-1, idx_t])*delta_T
            if idx_x == len(x)-1:
                C[idx_x,idx_y,idx_t+1] = ((A_1+A_5)*C[idx_x, idx_y, idx_t] + c_2*delta_X*A_1 + A_2*C[idx_x-1, idx_y, idx_t] + A_3*C[idx_x, idx_y+1, idx_t] + A_4*C[idx_x, idx_y-1, idx_t])*delta_T
            if idx_y == 0:
                C[idx_x,idx_y,idx_t+1] = (A_1*C[idx_x+1, idx_y, idx_t] + A_2*C[idx_x-1, idx_y, idx_t] + A_3*C[idx_x, idx_y+1, idx_t] + (A_4+A_5)*C[idx_x, idx_y, idx_t] - c_3*delta_Y*A_4)*delta_T
            if idx_y == len(y)-1:
                C[idx_x,idx_y,idx_t+1] = (A_1*C[idx_x+1, idx_y, idx_t] + A_2*C[idx_x-1, idx_y, idx_t] + (A_3+A_5)*C[idx_x, idx_y, idx_t] + c_4*delta_Y*A_3 + A_4*C[idx_x, idx_y-1, idx_t])*delta_T
            else:
                C[idx_x,idx_y,idx_t+1] = (A_1*C[idx_x+1, idx_y, idx_t] + A_2*C[idx_x-1, idx_y, idx_t] + A_3*C[idx_x, idx_y+1, idx_t] + A_4*C[idx_x, idx_y-1, idx_t] + A_5*C[idx_x, idx_y, idx_t])*delta_T
            idx_x += 1
        idx_y += 1
    idx_t += 1

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,7))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,C[:,:,t_akhir-1], cmap='magma')
plt.show()
```

can someone help me to solve it?

Comment: this looks more like a coding question than a math question, right?

Comment: Yes, and I also want to ask whether my equation is correct or not? If it's wrong, which part is wrong?